# Eclipse Javadoc link color in dark theme

Tags: eclipse

I am using Dark Theme in Eclipse and as of this week the Javadoc background and text color changed from black on white to white on dark grey. I am much happier with the way it looks now, except for the link color, which is barely readable now.

As you can see in the screenshot, there is no setting for Javadoc link color. I have also looked in the Basic folder, but there is no setting for link color there either.

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

I have found some posts about the link color in Javadoc in Ubuntu, where solutions were to change it in System wide settings. Unfortunately as I am on macOS I can't do that. Is there some other workaround for macOS?

Probably this is the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966903/how-to-edit-javadoc-popup-link-color-in-eclipse), except this is in the Javadoc panel and not the Tooltip.

Comment: See [Eclipse bug 517393](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517393)